# Retrieve notification type from userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, unnotificationrequest

Is there any way to retrieve what type (`local` or `remote`) notification fired `userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:` ?

I'm working on some kind of internal analytics module for my apps. In the each app I need to send to our analytics server specific information from notification userInfo and notification type (local or remote).

To get `userInfo` I'm using the following code:

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
    //app-specific logic goes here
    }
```

Of course when scheduling local notification, I can add specific parameter (to each app) to the `userInfo` to retrieve notification type. But might be more *clear* way exists to do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I'm just checking `userInfo` for specific keys that are mandatory in the remote push notifications payload (ex. "aps"). For my purposes this is enough. More information about remote notification payload: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html

Comment: Another option is to use `response.notification.request.trigger` to determine notification kind. No trigger == local, UNPushNotificationTrigger == remote.

Comment: Or rather UNPushNotificationTrigger == remote, Any other trigger == local.